# client fails in my sockstunnel case in python3

Tags: python-asyncio, tunnel, stunnel

I have a client/server case which is written in python by someone else, and it was working before.   Currently I am trying to see if I could have it re-executed but so far no luck.

Anyway, this is the python code on client side, which is written in python3 .

```
283  ->     ssl_ctx_client = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
284         ssl_ctx_client.check_hostname = False
285         ssl_ctx_client.options |= (
286             ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION
287         )
288         ssl_ctx_client.set_ciphers("ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256")
(Pdb++)
289         ssl_ctx_client.load_verify_locations(ssl_ca_file)
290         ssl_ctx_client.load_cert_chain(certfile=ssl_cert_file, keyfile=ssl_key_file)
291
292         # asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
293         loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
294         
295         # Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
296         coro_tunnel = loop.create_connection(
297             lambda: TunnelServer(is_server=False),
298             tunnel_host,
299             tunnel_port,
(Pdb++)
300             ssl=ssl_ctx_client,
301         )
302         
303         loop.run_until_complete(coro_tunnel)
304         
 ...
```

I have the server started first, but during the client call, it gives such return message:

```
/client.py", line 303, in socks_tunnel_client
    loop.run_until_complete(coro_tunnel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 985, in create_connection
    ssl_handshake_timeout=ssl_handshake_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1013, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
ConnectionResetError
```

If I was to find out the cause of this connection failure, what calls I should check first on the server side, that when client was to make call in "**_create_connection_transport**", what would be the relevant call triggered on server side ?

Thanks for the help.

Jack

Comment: You're sure you have the proper certificate files in the right place?

Comment: We have a set of certificate files checked in git, along with the rest client/server code.  So I am just reuse them. What I am not sure is, if the same set of certificate files still valid while the client/server case is running on a different host ?